# See all my RadTreeView nodes adding without freeze my UI

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, radtreeview

I have `Winforms` application and `RadTreeView`, all i want to do is to add dynamically nodes but i want to see this nodes adding without to freeze my UI.
This is what i have try:

```
private void Add()
{
    ThreadStart ts = delegate
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                radTreeView1.Nodes.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        });
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(ts);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
```

Currently my Ui stat but i cannot see my nodes adding but only after the for loop finish i can see all my nodes, of course without the `Thread` all mu Ui freeze, is it possible to see my nodes adding "ongoing" like in `ListView/GridView` ?

Comment: There your thread does nothing, insertion is still in UI thread (BTW it's right) all together. What you _may_ do is to dispatch adding of each node in the UI thread (keeping loop in your secondary thread). Of course this will slow down a lot your UI thread (but it won't be frozen) and you should do it only if there is much more (slow) logic than i.ToString() to calculate node content. I don't know telerik components but I'm sure there is something like lazy loading and virtual list (sibling nodes will be created when they become visible and children when node is expanded).

Comment: Can i have code example ? (i am a new developer...)